# Deleting row in database

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I want to delete the row which selected from `JTable` from database I have checked that my java program is connected to database but  i am confused how  to  delete entire row from `ms access` database without affecting or touching any column just wanted to delete the selected row in jtable

My database consists of 8 columns full name, father name, father cnic, date of birth, class, address, city and province

```
int x = MyTable.getSelectedRow();
String b = String.valueOf(MyTable.getValueAt(x, 1)); 

try {
     Connection con;
     Statement stmt;


    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//abdul//Desktop/StudentDatabase.accdb");


    stmt = con.createStatement();

    stmt.executeUpdate("delete from StudentDatabase where row = 'x'" );


    stmt.close();
    con.close();
   }
  catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stmt.executeUpdate("delete from StudentDatabase where row = 'x'" );
```

This SQL query is wrong. For example if you have following table in database, 
`CustomerID         CustomerName       ContactName
1               Mike              +248439533
2               Bob               +345353535`

and if you want to delete the row of "Mike" then you should write query as

`delete from StudentDatabase where CustomerName = 'Mike'`.

If you want to delete the row of CustomerID is "2", then you should write query as

`delete from StudentDatabase where CustomerID = 2`

In your case I hope this will your answer.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rowIndex = MyTable.getSelectedRow();
    String name = String.valueOf(MyTable.getValueAt(rowIndex, 1));

    try {
        Connection con;
        Statement stmt;


        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//abdul//Desktop/StudentDatabase.accdb");


        stmt = con.createStatement();

        int result = stmt.executeUpdate("delete from StudentDatabase where CustomerName = '"+name+"'" );

        if(result!=1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No record exists related to "+name);
        }



        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it's probably safer to `delete from StudentDatabase where CustomerID = 'C001'` There could be more than one rows with the name Mike

Comment: got your point is it possible if mike is replaced by a variable for example i ask user to enter the name he want to delete and if he input laura instead of mike so how to replace mike with laura and if any record does not exists by  the name of laura how to print that record does not exists

Comment: yeah it would be a conflict if there are mike more than one but in case of ID if that particular ID doesnt exists how to print sorry there is no record against this ID

Comment: @sugeesh bro this code works absolutely fine and i had also delted all my data  but  it  doesn't deltes the last row remianed in the database